# Play two sounds simultaneously using AVPLayer iOS

Tags: ios, avplayer

I'm using two instances of `AVPlayer`.

First player audio is working fine but the moment the second audio starts there is a small fraction of time in which the first audio stops.

For first player I have made a singleton class.
This is the second player.

```
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset]        //AVPlayerItem *playerItem=[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
[self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem]
[self.player play];
```

Comment: It looks to me like you might be using just one AVPlayer (`self.player`). If you have two players, I would expect to see instance variables `self.player1` and `self.player2` or similar. Please show more code to prove you've got two independent AVPlayer objects that persist simultaneously.

Comment: This is the second player using singleton class

@interface TwiloBackgroundMusicPlayer : AVPlayer


........In the main class

 [[TwiloBackgroundMusicPlayer sharedPlayer] setCurrentURL:url];


        [[TwiloBackgroundMusicPlayer sharedPlayer] setMusicPlayerDelegate:self];
        
        [[TwiloBackgroundMusicPlayer sharedPlayer]loadVideo:url];

   
.........    
-(void)loadVideo:(NSURL *)URL {


 NSArray *requestedKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tracks", @"duration", nil];


   [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:requestedKeys completionHandler:{
}

];


}